# Should interface/abstract class contains only pure virtual methods?

Tags: c++

I am a bit weak with designing and I wonder whether it's a good design to have simple virtual methods (not only pure virtual) in an interface? I have a class that is some kind of interface:

```
class IModel {
    void initialize(...);
    void render(...);

    int getVertexCount() const;
    int getAnotherField() const;
};
```

the initialize and render methods need to be reimplemented for sure, so they are good candidates for pure virtual methods. However, the two last methods are very simple and practically always with the same implementation (just returning some field). Can I leave them as virtual methods with default implementation or is it better to have it pure virtual that needs to be reimplemented, because it's an interface?

Comment: At the very least, you should have a virtual destructor. And you should probably give it an empty body so derived classes aren't forced to implement it.

Comment: It's up to you, and how strictly you want to follow various dogmas. The language doesn't enforce anything of this. Having a default implementation in the base class can be practical, but is seen as "impure" by some believers.

Comment: @juanchopanza isn't it even so that if you have no virtual destructor and deleting a pointer to IModel none of the drived classes destructors will be called. there is no way that drived classes could implement it.

Comment: @mgr I actually don't understand what you are saying. But a base class that will be used for runtime polymorphism absolutely must have a virtual destructor. And it *should* have a an implementation, because the derived classes might not need to do anything special in the destructor, in which case they shouldn't be forced to implement an empty one.

Comment: @juanchopanza but even if the drived classe would implement a destructor and the base class did not. it would not get called if you delete a pointer to the base class of a drived class. this is why you definitely need a virtual destructor in the base class.

Comment: @mgr that is why I said the base class should at the very least have a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to point out some differences:

there is no such thing as "some kind of Interface", is this class supposed to be an Interface or an Abstract Class?

If it's supposed to be an Interface then the answer is: all its methods must be **pure virtual** (no implementation) and it must **not** contain fields, not even one. The most you can (must, actually) do is, like jaunchopanza said, giving an empty body to the virtual destructor, thus allowing the derived classes to be destructed accordingly.

If, instead, it's supposed to be an Abstract Class then you're free to add the fields `m_vertexCount` and `m_anotherField` (I suppose) and implement `getVertexCount()` and ՝getAnotherField()՝ as you please. However, you should **not** name it `IModel`, because the `I` prefix should be used only for Interfaces.

Edit: I think I'm one of those "Believers" of which Bo Persson is talking about :)

Comment: Actually, I thought the "interface" and "abstract class" are interchangable in C++ since the language doesn't give you interface keyword like in e.g. Java, so the concept of interface is performed by abstract class. So I think I will go for abstract class then, because I have few methods just returning a field, so it would be uncomfortable to always reimplement it and breaking the DRY concept (because practically they will have always the same body).

Comment: Yes indeed: technically C++ does not support interfaces but only abstract classes.
However, the moment you name a class `ISomething` you're implicitly giving it an interface meaning and, since the two _concepts_ of interface and abstract classes are not interchangeable, you are depriving it of the possibility of having non-pure-virtual methods.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing a trade-off between code repetition and readability. The reader of your code will derive good help from every pure interface and from every non-overridden method. However, the default implementation wil be duplicated by every subclass. Whether or not you should provide a default implementation depends on the likelihood that the default implementation will change and will then need to be changed all over the place.

Without knowing these details, a hard yes-or-no answer cannot be given.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is make `IModel` be an interface and provide base class, eg `ModelBase` that implements common/repeating functionality.

```
class IModel
{
    virtual void initialize(...) = 0;
    virtual void render(...) = 0

    virtual int getVertexCount() const = 0;
    virtual int getAnotherField() const = 0;
};

class ModelBase : public IModel
{
    // common functions
    virtual int getVertexCount() const override { return vertexCount_; }
    virtual int getAnotherField() const override { return anotherField_; }

protected:
    int vertexCount_ = 0, anotherField_ = 0;
};

class MyModel : public ModelBase
{
    virtual void initialize(...) override { ... }
    virtual void render(...) override { ... }
};
```

The one downside of this approach is that there will be some (probably negligible) performance penalty due to extra virtual functions and loss of optimizations by the compiler.